# onclick input type submit

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe

In a form I have an `<iframe>` that contains a PHP file (editor.php). This PHP file contains an HTML form.

Well, when I do a "submit form", I call the same PHP file, for example main.php.
When I press the submit button, I have "onclick method" that it calls a Javascript function inside editor.php. This function executes the form.

My problem is that main form is executed correctly but the second form is not.

In the second loop of the form of editor.php receives nothing.

Comment: add source for reference

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your code? This would help to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Check this way it will work as you expected**
//main.php
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateMain()
    {
       alert('main'); 
    }
    function validateSub()
    {
        alert('sub'); 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>  
<form id="main"  onsubmit="return validateMain();">
        <input type="text" name="first" id="first"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Main"/> 
 </form>
 <iframe name="ifr-form" id="ifr-form" src="test.html"></iframe> 
</body>
</html>

//test.html the second form included through iframe

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>


 <form id="sub" onclick="return window.top.validateSub();">
        <input type="text" name="first" id="second"/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit Sub" /> 
      </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Sam, but the second form has to rescue the variables of the form and write in html file.

Comment: @jordi ,, Check out the code jordi........is it ok for you? or you expect something more ...if you want means let me know as soon as possible

Comment: @jordi give me an up vote for this content ,,, and clearly tell me the exact way of asking,,,,,,,give me the relevant part of the code from your side

Answer (score -2):

you must check if php and iframe are compatible, as far as i Know I don't think that frames and php gives any output, hope this helps.

Comment: Since an iframe is just a place to display that .php file there is nothing to worry about "compatibility" issues.

Comment: <form id="form1" name="form1" action="Nb_AnadirPuntoMapa.php?nloads=1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="<?php GuardaNuevoPunto();?>">

call iframe...